# Values Getting Skewed When Passed Between Scripts Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a portal system and am up to making the traveller go through the portal. For this, I just set the traveller's position to the position of the other portal. When I do this, however, the Z rotation of the camera gets skewed, and they are teleported slightly higher than they should. Any help is welcome <3

**Portal Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Portal : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Portal Camera Positioning
    public Portal linkedPortal;
    private Camera portalCam;
    private Camera playerCam;
    
    //Portal Sceen Texture
    private PortalScreen portalScreen;
    private MeshRenderer screenRen;
    private RenderTexture viewTexture;

    //Travellers
    //[SerializableField]
    List<PortalTraveller> trackedTravellers;
    public Vector3 desiredCameraRotation;
    public Vector3 desiredCameraPosition;
    private Transform globalRuler;
    PortalTraveller[] travellersToAdd;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float travellerDistance;


    //Debug
    [HideInInspector]
    public float dstToPlayer;

    void Awake()
    {
        playerCam = Camera.main;
        portalCam = linkedPortal.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        portalScreen = GetComponentInChildren<PortalScreen>();
        screenRen = portalScreen.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        globalRuler = GameObject.FindWithTag("GlobalRuler").transform;
        trackedTravellers = new List<PortalTraveller>();
        travellersToAdd = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<PortalTraveller>();

        foreach (PortalTraveller traveller in travellersToAdd)
        {
            if (!trackedTravellers.Contains(traveller))
            {
                trackedTravellers.Add(traveller);
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Render();   
    }

    static bool VisibleFromCamera(Renderer renderer, Camera camera)
    {
        Plane[] frustumPlanes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera);
        return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(frustumPlanes, renderer.bounds);
    }

    void Render()
    {
        if (!VisibleFromCamera(screenRen, playerCam))
        {
            return;
        }
        
        desiredCameraPosition = transform.position - (playerCam.transform.position - linkedPortal.portalScreen.screenPos);
        desiredCameraPosition.y = playerCam.transform.position.y;
        desiredCameraRotation = playerCam.transform.eulerAngles + new Vector3 (0f, 180f, 0f);

        portalCam.transform.position = desiredCameraPosition;
        portalCam.transform.eulerAngles = desiredCameraRotation;

        if (viewTexture == null || viewTexture.width != Screen.width || viewTexture.height != Screen.height)
        {
            if (viewTexture != null)
            {
                viewTexture.Release();
            }

            viewTexture = new RenderTexture (Screen.width, Screen.height, 0); 
            portalCam.targetTexture = viewTexture;
            screenRen.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", viewTexture);
        }
    }
    
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        HandleTravellers();
    }

    void HandleTravellers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < trackedTravellers.Count; i++)
        {
            PortalTraveller traveller = trackedTravellers[i];
            Transform travellerT = trackedTravellers[i].transform;

            Vector3 toTraveller = traveller.transform.position - transform.position;
            int portalSide = System.Math.Sign(Vector3.Dot(toTraveller, transform.right));
            int portalSideOld = System.Math.Sign(Vector3.Dot(traveller.previousTravellerVector, transform.right));
            travellerDistance = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, travellerT.position));

            //Debug.Log("Handled");
            if (travellerDistance > linkedPortal.travellerDistance)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (portalSide < portalSideOld && travellerDistance < globalRuler.transform.lossyScale.z / 2 )
            {
                //Debug.Log(travellerDistance);
                
                var positionOld = travellerT.position;
                var rotationOld = travellerT.rotation;
                Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(desiredCameraRotation.x, desiredCameraRotation.y, 0f);

                traveller.Teleport(transform, linkedPortal.transform, desiredCamerxaPosition, rot);
                traveller.previousTravellerVector = toTraveller;                
                //trackedTravellers.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                traveller.previousTravellerVector = toTraveller;
                dstToPlayer = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, travellerT.position));
            }
        }
    }

    void OnValidate()
    {
        if (linkedPortal != null)
        {
            linkedPortal.linkedPortal = this;
        }
        travellersToAdd = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<PortalTraveller>();
    }
}
```

**Traveller Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PortalTraveller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 previousTravellerVector;

    public void Teleport(Transform originalPortal, Transform linkedPortal, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
    {
        transform.position = pos;
        transform.rotation = rot;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does Teleport in the traveler script take two transforms and you ignore them both?

Comment: Also a bug in your code - `desiredCamerxaPosition` isn't defined. Can't tell if you've given us the code you're running or not because that shouldn't compile. I would expect a camera to be basically over-the-shoulder or about face height, and when you `Teleport` you're passing the desired camera position, but then as I hint above you're not using the `linkedPortal.position` to set the `PortalTraveller` position, you're instead using the `desiredCamerxaPosition`, so you're putting the player's feet where their shoulder/face would be.

Comment: For the rotation you'd need to define what "skewed" means.

Comment: @Chuck this code is just test code to see if my approach will work. I will use those transforms later. Thanks for picking up that typo in my ```desiredCameraPosition```. I'm honestly not sure why it didn't give me an error either. The camera's rotation gets skewed on the z axis, which it should never be rotating on, giving a kind of 'tilted' view. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I didn't really see anything that looks like it would rotate about the z axis, but there is this line `desiredCameraRotation = playerCam.transform.eulerAngles + new Vector3 (0f, 180f, 0f);` and I've definitely seen inconsistencies when trying to use Euler angles. If you're trying to rotate 180 degrees about up then try using RotateAround and pass the camera origin, Vector3.up, and 180f as args instead of trying to convert to Euler angles and back. Anything more than a simple rotation about one axis usually results in really weird angles.

Comment: @Chuck I'll try that out and get back to you

Comment: @Chuck I managed to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ayyy happy you got it! Hope your project turns out how you imagined it. Good luck! :)